# Ошибка function is not defined, не знаю в чем проблема

Tags: javascript, html

Вообще я хотел в начале задать другой вопрос, но когда здесь написал код, появилась ошибка: "Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollHook is not defined". Не знаю чем вызвано, вроде бы написал название функции правильно. Это я слепой что не вижу синтаксической ошибки или это что то другое? Подскажите пожалуйста

```js
function scrollHook(offsetValue, element){
 let thisElement = document.getElementById(element);
 window.onscroll = function (){
  if (window.pageYOffset > offsetValue ) {
    
   thisElement.style.overflow = "scroll";
      
  } else if(window.pageYOffset < offsetValue){
    
   thisElement.style.overflow = "hidden";

  }
 };
};
```

```css
.display{
 display: flex;
 margin-top: 250px;
}
.scroll{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">  
  <div class="scroll" id="block-a"> <div class="block">a</div> </div>
  <div class="scroll" id="block-b"> <div class="block">b</div> </div>
</div>



<script>
  scrollHook("250", "block-a");
  scrollHook("250", "block-b");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помещайте весь скрипт в окно HTML, или весь скрипт - в окно JavaScript.

В собраной странице сначала идет HTML, a потом JS.

```css
.display {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.scroll {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <div class="scroll" id="block-a">
    <div class="block">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll" id="block-b">
    <div class="block">b</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function scrollHook(offsetValue, element) {
    let thisElement = document.getElementById(element);
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > offsetValue) {
        thisElement.style.overflow = "scroll";
      } else if (window.pageYOffset < offsetValue) {
        thisElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
      }
    };
  };
</script>

<script>
  scrollHook("250", "block-a");
  scrollHook("250", "block-b");
</script>
```

---

Вопрос: После двух вызовов `scrollHook`, чему будет равно `window.onscroll`?

Ответ: `window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { ... });`

Comment: Вообще, с этим у меня изначально и была проблема. У меня происходило так, что только второй вызов работал, а первый игнорировало. Не знаете как исправить это? На странице находятся 2 div, к которым нужно применить одну и ту же функцию.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!